# Print numbers in a concentric square pattern

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, ascii-art

I am trying to solve a programming problem on a coding platform. When I execute it on my PC, it works perfectly, but when I submit the code on the coding platform, it throws a "Time Limit Exceeded" error. Can someone check my solution and help optimize it?

> Given a number N, the program must print the pattern as described below.
>
> Input Format:The first line contains the value of the N which represent the number N.
> Output Format:The pattern as described below in the Example.

```
> Input: 4

> Output:
4444444
4333334
4322234
4321234
4322234
4333334   
4444444
```

**My Approach**

Print Upper rectangle and then print the lower rectangle.

The problem statement and my code can also be found [here](http://ideone.com/7Fxkv2).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test004_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        /*  PRINT UPPER PART
            4444444
            4333334
            4322234
            4321234
        */
        for(int i = N; i>(1); i--)
        {
            for(int j = N; j >i; j--)
                System.out.print(j);
            for(int j = 0; j<(i*2)-1; j++)
               System.out.print(i);
            for(int j = i+1; j<=N; j++)
                System.out.print(j);
            System.out.println("");
        }
        /* 
            PRINT LOWER PART
            4322234
            4333334
            4444444
        */
        for(int i = 1; i<=(N); i++)
        {
            for(int j = N; j>i; j--)
                System.out.print(j);
            for(int j = 0; j<(i*2)-1; j++)
                System.out.print(i);
            for(int j = i+1; j <=N; j++)
                System.out.print(j);
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the "Time limit exceeded". The code runs really fast.

Comment: Do you know of a time limit? This takes to `2 ms` for input of `4` and `100 ms` for input of `100` on my Macbook Pro, which as @RolandIllig said is pretty quick.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the programming challenge?  It's possible that someone might suggest something specific to that online judge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been said by @200_success, outputting individual characters at a time to the console is going to be relatively slow.  You'd be better off building up the string using a StringBuilder and then writing the whole thing at the end.

Assuming a maximum number of 9, you can predict the size of the required buffer which will prevent the buffer from needing to resize.  A *safe* value would be:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(N*2*N*2)
```

This number will need to be bigger if you have to support multiple digit numbers, however the `StringBuilder` will scale this for you if required.

Instead of calling `System.out.print`, you then append to the `StringBuilder`:

```
sb.append(j);
```

Adding new lines when required:

```
sb.append("\n");
```

And at the end, write out the entire buffer in one go:

```
System.out.print(sb);
```

**Putting it together**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int N = sc.nextInt();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(N*2*N*2);
    for(int i = N; i>(1); i--) //Print upper part
    {
        for(int j = N; j >i; j--)
            sb.append(j);
        for(int j = 0; j<(i*2)-1; j++)
           sb.append(i);
        for(int j = i+1; j<=N; j++)
            sb.append(j);
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    for(int i = 1; i<=(N); i++)// print lower part
    {
        for(int j = N; j>i; j--)
            sb.append(j);
        for(int j = 0; j<(i*2)-1; j++)
            sb.append(i);
        for(int j = i+1; j <=N; j++)
            sb.append(j);
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    System.out.print(sb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir it worked, but i dont understand why `System.out.println()` is creating problem it taken constant time`O(1)` on the other hand StringBuilder class also takes `O(1)` time to buildup the string.

Comment: @Rajatk95 because whilst they may be the same number of operations, each operation takes longer. String builder is simply appending a character to a buffer. Print needs to call out to an operating system function to write to video memory, which is more complex and slower.  Consider two calls to sleep, one for a second and one for two seconds.  They are both constant time, however over of the calls takes twice as long.

Answer (score 3):

The individual `System.out.print()` calls are probably resulting in too much system call overhead. Try printing an entire line at a time, or even the entire pattern as one very long string.